# Azure pipelines can't find test results file

Tags: azure, karma-jasmine

I realize that a similar question has been asked [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59905681/azure-pipeline-cant-find-test-results-files-to-publish) However, not only has no answer been accepted, but the answer isn't really an answer.

I have a very simple build pipeline that builds a nx workspace and tests it. The issue that I am seeing is that when I run the test portion of the pipeline, test results files are created but the publish test results task can't find the files.

My karma.conf.js is as follows

```js
// Karma configuration file, see link for more information
// https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/configuration-file.html

const { join } = require("path");
const { constants } = require("karma");

module.exports = () => {
    return {
        basePath: "",
        frameworks: ["jasmine", "@angular-devkit/build-angular"],
        plugins: [
            require("karma-jasmine"),
            require("karma-chrome-launcher"),
            require("karma-jasmine-html-reporter"),
            require("@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma"),
            require("karma-coverage"),
            require("karma-mocha-reporter"),
            require("karma-nunit2-reporter"),
            require("karma-spec-reporter"),
        ],
        client: {
            clearContext: false,
            jasmine: {
                random: false,
            },
        },
        jasmineHtmlReporter: {
            suppressAll: true,
        },
        reporters: ["mocha", "coverage", "spec", "nunit"],
        mochaReporter: {
            output: "minimal",
            ignoreSkipped: true,
            maxLogLines: 5,
        },
        nunitReporter: {
            outputFile: "src\\e2e\\test-results\\TEST-karma.xml",
        },
        reportSlowerThan: 500,
        port: 9876,
        colors: true,
        logLevel: constants.LOG_INFO,
        autoWatch: true,
        browsers: ["Chrome"],
        singleRun: false,
        restartOnFileChange: true,
        customLaunchers: {
            chromeDebugging: {
                base: "Chrome",
                flags: ["--remote-debugging-port=9333"],
            },
            headlessChrome: {
                base: "ChromeHeadless",
                flags: [
                    "--no-sandbox",
                    "--no-proxy-server",
                    "--disable-web-security",
                    "--disable-gpu",
                    "--js-flags=-max-old-space-size=8196",
                ],
            },
        },
        preprocessors: {
            "src/**/*.js": ["coverage"],
        },
    };
};
```

And the relevant portions of the pipeline configuration are:

```yaml
      - script: npx nx affected --target=test --parallel --max-parallel=2 --no-watch --browsers headlessChrome --reporters nunit
        displayName: Test Affected Projects
      - script: cd apps/portfolio/src/e2e/test-results && ls
        condition: succeededOrFailed()
      - task: PublishTestResults@2
        condition: succeededOrFailed()
        inputs:
          testResultsFormat: NUnit
          searchFolder: "$(system.defaultWorkingDirectory)/**/src/e2e/test-results"
          testResultsFiles: "TEST-karma.xml"
          mergeTestResults: true
```

Overall the pipeline succeeds but the output is not what I was expecting.

```
2022-03-11T15:06:33.8808764Z ##[section]Starting: Test Affected Projects
2022-03-11T15:06:33.8816403Z ==============================================================================
2022-03-11T15:06:33.8816705Z Task         : Command line
2022-03-11T15:06:33.8816986Z Description  : Run a command line script using Bash on Linux and macOS and cmd.exe on Windows
2022-03-11T15:06:33.8817255Z Version      : 2.200.2
2022-03-11T15:06:33.8817446Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2022-03-11T15:06:33.8817875Z Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line
2022-03-11T15:06:33.8818232Z ==============================================================================
2022-03-11T15:06:34.0062774Z Generating script.
2022-03-11T15:06:34.0070315Z Script contents:
2022-03-11T15:06:34.0071200Z npx nx affected --target=test --parallel --max-parallel=2 --no-watch --browsers headlessChrome --reporters nunit
2022-03-11T15:06:34.0071854Z ========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
2022-03-11T15:06:34.0090870Z [command]/usr/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /home/vsts/work/_temp/f1d1558c-ec90-4297-a8d7-21c5560acce3.sh
2022-03-11T15:06:34.8996294Z 
2022-03-11T15:06:34.9036218Z  >  NX   No explicit --base argument provided, but found environment variable NX_BASE so using its value as the affected base: $(git rev-parse origin/main)
2022-03-11T15:06:34.9037131Z 
2022-03-11T15:06:34.9037511Z 
2022-03-11T15:06:34.9038616Z  >  NX   No explicit --head argument provided, but found environment variable NX_HEAD so using its value as the affected head: 7e6371ebd645b9aea7aba9dc5dcef876334321a2
2022-03-11T15:06:34.9039279Z 
2022-03-11T15:06:50.7772679Z 
2022-03-11T15:06:50.7774790Z > nx run portfolio:test --no-watch --browsers=headlessChrome --reporters=nunit
2022-03-11T15:06:50.7775838Z - Generating browser application bundles (phase: setup)...
2022-03-11T15:06:50.7777536Z [32m10 03 2022 21:26:42.906:INFO [preprocessor.coverage]: [39mcoverage not included in reporters [ 'nunit' ]
2022-03-11T15:06:50.7778372Z ✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
2022-03-11T15:06:50.7779633Z [32m10 03 2022 21:26:50.156:INFO [karma-server]: [39mKarma v6.3.17 server started at http://localhost:9876/
2022-03-11T15:06:50.7780634Z [32m10 03 2022 21:26:50.157:INFO [launcher]: [39mLaunching browsers headlessChrome with concurrency unlimited
2022-03-11T15:06:50.7781477Z [32m10 03 2022 21:26:50.165:INFO [launcher]: [39mStarting browser ChromeHeadless
2022-03-11T15:06:50.7782434Z [32m10 03 2022 21:26:54.147:INFO [Chrome Headless 99.0.4844.51 (Linux x86_64)]: [39mConnected on socket XMnFRYM5I2QyT8ZWAAAB with id 75945850
2022-03-11T15:06:50.7782830Z 
2022-03-11T15:06:50.7785244Z  
2022-03-11T15:06:50.7785379Z 
2022-03-11T15:06:50.8883421Z 
2022-03-11T15:06:50.8885915Z > nx run home:test --no-watch --browsers=headlessChrome --reporters=nunit
2022-03-11T15:06:50.8886904Z - Generating browser application bundles (phase: setup)...
2022-03-11T15:06:50.8888008Z [32m10 03 2022 21:21:54.923:INFO [preprocessor.coverage]: [39mcoverage not included in reporters [ 'nunit' ]
2022-03-11T15:06:50.8888994Z ✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
2022-03-11T15:06:50.8890710Z [32m10 03 2022 21:22:08.464:INFO [karma-server]: [39mKarma v6.3.17 server started at http://localhost:9876/
2022-03-11T15:06:50.8891823Z [32m10 03 2022 21:22:08.465:INFO [launcher]: [39mLaunching browsers headlessChrome with concurrency unlimited
2022-03-11T15:06:50.8892684Z [32m10 03 2022 21:22:08.469:INFO [launcher]: [39mStarting browser ChromeHeadless
2022-03-11T15:06:50.8893639Z [32m10 03 2022 21:22:19.091:INFO [Chrome Headless 99.0.4844.51 (Linux x86_64)]: [39mConnected on socket kf6bzFTypLCiZrEeAAAB with id 63557301
2022-03-11T15:06:50.8894051Z 
2022-03-11T15:06:50.8896419Z  
2022-03-11T15:06:50.8896796Z 
2022-03-11T15:06:51.0715055Z 
2022-03-11T15:06:51.0716746Z > nx run core-ui:test --no-watch --browsers=headlessChrome --reporters=nunit
2022-03-11T15:06:51.0717452Z - Generating browser application bundles (phase: setup)...
2022-03-11T15:06:51.0718458Z [32m10 03 2022 21:21:54.930:INFO [preprocessor.coverage]: [39mcoverage not included in reporters [ 'nunit' ]
2022-03-11T15:06:51.0719083Z ✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
2022-03-11T15:06:51.0719931Z [32m10 03 2022 21:22:08.422:INFO [karma-server]: [39mKarma v6.3.17 server started at http://localhost:9877/
2022-03-11T15:06:51.0720750Z [32m10 03 2022 21:22:08.423:INFO [launcher]: [39mLaunching browsers headlessChrome with concurrency unlimited
2022-03-11T15:06:51.0721448Z [32m10 03 2022 21:22:08.427:INFO [launcher]: [39mStarting browser ChromeHeadless
2022-03-11T15:06:51.0722283Z [32m10 03 2022 21:22:19.091:INFO [Chrome Headless 99.0.4844.51 (Linux x86_64)]: [39mConnected on socket fE5V6U9cgdViTj6nAAAB with id 33194964
2022-03-11T15:06:51.0722643Z 
2022-03-11T15:06:51.0722824Z  
2022-03-11T15:06:51.0722903Z 
2022-03-11T15:06:51.0722994Z 
2022-03-11T15:06:51.0723244Z  >  NX   Successfully completed running the command.
2022-03-11T15:06:51.0723403Z 
2022-03-11T15:06:51.0723725Z    See run details at https://nx.app/runs/8yGag21GbWW
2022-03-11T15:06:51.0723889Z 
2022-03-11T15:06:51.0902196Z ##[section]Finishing: Test Affected Projects


2022-03-11T15:06:51.0928478Z ##[section]Starting: CmdLine
2022-03-11T15:06:51.0936040Z ==============================================================================
2022-03-11T15:06:51.0936338Z Task         : Command line
2022-03-11T15:06:51.0936623Z Description  : Run a command line script using Bash on Linux and macOS and cmd.exe on Windows
2022-03-11T15:06:51.0936913Z Version      : 2.200.2
2022-03-11T15:06:51.0937102Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2022-03-11T15:06:51.0937396Z Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line
2022-03-11T15:06:51.0937799Z ==============================================================================
2022-03-11T15:06:51.2211419Z Generating script.
2022-03-11T15:06:51.2219976Z Script contents:
2022-03-11T15:06:51.2221506Z cd apps/portfolio/src/e2e/test-results && ls
2022-03-11T15:06:51.2221892Z ========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
2022-03-11T15:06:51.2241765Z [command]/usr/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /home/vsts/work/_temp/5e4cb0b9-23dd-43cd-952b-d4c9b74f3483.sh
2022-03-11T15:06:51.2304790Z TEST-karma.xml
2022-03-11T15:06:51.2362372Z ##[section]Finishing: CmdLine


2022-03-11T15:06:51.2382031Z ##[section]Starting: PublishTestResults
2022-03-11T15:06:51.2387550Z ==============================================================================
2022-03-11T15:06:51.2387836Z Task         : Publish Test Results
2022-03-11T15:06:51.2388062Z Description  : Publish test results to Azure Pipelines
2022-03-11T15:06:51.2388276Z Version      : 2.198.0
2022-03-11T15:06:51.2388503Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2022-03-11T15:06:51.2388799Z Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/publish-test-results
2022-03-11T15:06:51.2389162Z ==============================================================================
2022-03-11T15:06:51.3780924Z [command]/usr/bin/dotnet --version
2022-03-11T15:06:51.5740113Z 6.0.200
2022-03-11T15:06:51.5794851Z ##[warning]No test result files matching TEST-karma.xml were found.
2022-03-11T15:06:51.6214350Z ##[section]Finishing: PublishTestResults
```

As is evident in the second section of the logs above, the file exists but according to the step after that, no files exist.

I get the same results whether I use JUnit or NUnit and a majority of my configuration is copied from a working pipeline at my work.

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer by messing around with the configuration for the pipeline:

```yaml
      - task: PublishTestResults@2
        condition: succeededOrFailed()
        inputs:
          testResultsFormat: NUnit
          testResultsFiles: "**/TEST-*.xml"
          mergeTestResults: true
```

rather than having a search folder and a testResultsFiles property i used only the testResultsFiles property and prefixed it with a recursive search for any file that starts with TEST- and is an xml file